# MongoDB and Pymongo, query FULLTEXT in all collections

Tags: python, database, mongodb, jupyter-notebook, pymongo

I have a local MongoDB database with multiple collections.
I use pymongo in jupyter notebook, what I would like to do is run a query **FULLTEXT** looking for the data on **all the collections present**.
is it possible to do this? if so how could i proceed?

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017/')
client.list_database_names()
out: ['admin', 'config', 'local']
```

In local I have a more collection:
this is what I do with just one collection

```
db = client["local"]
firstdb = db["firstdb"]

result = db.firstdb.find({"email": {"$regex":"test","$options": 'i'}})
for item in result:
    print(item['email'],item['log'])
```

in essence I would like to perform an **email query** also on **secondb**, **thirdb**, **fourthdb**, etc. etc.

Answer (score 0):

no one can help me? basically I have to do a **FULLTEXT** query on **all collections**.

the only solution I found is this:

```
result = db.firstdb.find({"email": {"$regex":"test","$options": 'i'}})
result1 = db.secondb.find({"email": {"$regex":"test","$options": 'i'}})
result2 = db.thirdb.find({"email": {"$regex":"test","$options": 'i'}})



for item in result:
    print(item['email'],item['log'])
for item in result1:
    print(item['email'],item['date'])
for item in result2:
    print(item['email'],item['account'])
```

but I'm not sure I'm going on the right track!

I thank anyone who can help me!

PS: I would not like to change the structure of the collections, the problem could occur in other Database